# Thank you so much for Workplace Stack Exchange

Tags: support

I don't know where to write this but FWIW just wanted to say that this site has totally saved my you-know-what in a complex and perplexing past few months. It also immensely clarified so much gut-instinct and other feelings I had. Being Western-educated but having to spend lots of time in an Asian country... well, just thanks. I cannot express my appreciation enough.

Comment: you-know-what = posterior ?

Comment: @Kilisi you-know-it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most welcome, and if you ever face a situation which you think requires discussion, please feel free to stop by chat in ["The water cooler"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler)  many of us hang out there and can provide additional help

Answer (score 4):

You’re very welcome, we do our best to offer the best answers we can.

The green tick of success is the best reward we can hope for!